# Proving that this sequence converges using the epsilon definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this sequence $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ and I'm trying to get a better understanding how to apply the epsilon definition of convergence.

I want to prove that this sequence converges to $0$ using this definition.

Here are my steps so far:

$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N_0\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq n_0:|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon$

---

$|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon$

$\iff (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^2<\epsilon ^2$

$\iff (n+1)-2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n<\epsilon^2$

$\iff 2n+1-2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}<\epsilon^2$

$\iff 2n-2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}<\epsilon^2-1$

$\iff 2(n-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1})<\epsilon ^2 -1$

$\iff n-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}<\frac{\epsilon ^2 -1}{2}$

From here on, I'm not completely sure if I'm doing it correctly

$\Rightarrow 2n-n^2=n-n^2+n=n-n(n+1)<n-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}<\frac{\epsilon^2 -1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow n^2> \frac{\epsilon^2 -1}{6}$

And now I don't know how to remove the exponent. I can't use the square root since the right hand side is not always positive.

What is the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use that $$|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon\iff (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})<\epsilon(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}).$$ That is:

$$1<\epsilon(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}).$$

Note that if $n\ge \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: May I ask how did you get $n\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$? Using your hint I got $n>\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1}{2}$.

Comment: Note that if $n\ge \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ then $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}.$ We could have taken $n\ge \dfrac{1}{2\epsilon^2}.$ In such a case $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}>2\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}.$

Comment: We know that $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. But how do you know that $\sqrt{n}\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: You have to choose $N$ that depends on $\epsilon.$ If you choose $N$ such that $\sqrt{N}\ge \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then $n\ge N\implies |\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon.$

Comment: I see, so we can have more than 1 value? Does that mean all $N>\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1}{2}$, $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}$, $N>\frac{1}{2\epsilon ^2}$ are correct?

Comment: I have not checked if the first works. But the others yes. You are right, there are more than one value. Note that if N works then N+1,2N, ... also works.

Comment: One last question: Could you please check the steps I made in my post above for correctness? It would really help my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $n=\sinh^2(t)$ and compute

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(t)}-\sinh(t)\right)=$$

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty} e^{-t}.$$

for $\epsilon>0$ given,

we take $A=\ln(\frac 1\epsilon)$.

$t>A \implies e^{-t}<\epsilon$.

the limit is zero.

Comment: Where are you using the epsilon definition?

Comment: @mfl I used $\epsilon-A$.